# Set containment bounding box on a SKMapView

Tags: ios, skmaps

I'd like to set a "containment bounding box" for a SKMapView to disallow an user to navigate, let's say for example, out of the Germany bounding box (I've coordinates of the desired container)

I guess I've to use

```
mapView:didChangeToRegion:
```

and

```
mapView:didStartRegionChangeFromRegion:
```

But I can't get it to work comparing previous visibleRegion with new visibleRegion.

Any idea on how to manage that ?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could do it by just implementing mapView:didChangeToRegion:

```
if (![self.bbox containsLocation:region.center] || region.zoomLevel < self.minZoom) { 
    SKCoordinateRegion allowedRegion = region; 
    if (region.center.latitude > self.bbox.topLeftCoordinate.latitude) { 
        allowedRegion.center.latitude = self.bbox.topLeftCoordinate.latitude; 
    } else if (region.center.latitude < self.bbox.bottomRightCoordinate.latitude) { 
        allowedRegion.center.latitude = self.bbox.bottomRightCoordinate.latitude; 
    } 

    if (region.center.longitude > self.bbox.bottomRightCoordinate.longitude) { 
        allowedRegion.center.longitude = self.bbox.bottomRightCoordinate.longitude; 
    } else if (region.center.longitude < self.bbox.topLeftCoordinate.longitude) { 
        allowedRegion.center.longitude = self.bbox.topLeftCoordinate.longitude; 
    } 

    if (region.zoomLevel < self.minZoom) { 
        allowedRegion.zoomLevel = self.minZoom; 
    } 

    mapView.visibleRegion = allowedRegion; 

}
```

Where self.bbox is an SKBoundingBox with your desired allowed bounding box. 
 and self.minZoom is the minimum allowed zoom level.

It's not ideal though, for 2 reasons: 
1. When you try to cross the bounding box boundaries the map wiggles a bit back and forth. 
2. Bounding box is not ideal for enclosing a country. A simplified polygon would be better.